# Python webtest multipart form set request payload

Tags: python, mocking, multipartform-data, webtest

I'd like to get webtest to run a multipart form post using Mock. The issue I have is the request payload is missing.

Here's my request using webtest:

```
res = app.post(
        my_url,
        upload_files=files
    )
```

Pyramid's DummyRequest

```
boundary = "my random string"
content_type = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary
headers = {"Content-Type":content_type}
from base64 import standard_b64encode
body = standard_b64encode(boundary)
body += standard_b64encode("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\"")
body += standard_b64encode("Content-Type: */*")                           
body += actual_file
from pyramid.testing import DummyRequest
request = testing.DummyRequest(path=my_path, headers=headers, body=body, post="lmnop")
request.context = testing.DummyResource()
from somewhere import MyClass
imitate = MyClass(request)
response = imitate.formMethod()
self.assertEqual('200 Success', response.status)
```

Has anyone had any luck to set request payload for a dummy multipart form request?

I couldn't find how to get `webtest.forms.Upload` to play nice, since I can create my object there. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.